# Python: can a function return a string?

Tags: python, string, recursion

I am making a recursive function that slices string until it is empty. When it is empty it alternatively selects the characters and is supposed to print or return the value. In this case I am expecting my function to return two words 'Hello' and 'World'. Maybe I have got it all wrong but what I don't understand is that my function doesn't let me print or return string. I am not asking for help but I'd like some explanation :) thanks

```
def lsubstr(x):
    a= ''
    b= ''
    if x == '':
        return ''
    else:
        a = a + x[0:]
        b = b + x[1:]
        lsubstr(x[2:])
        #print (a,b)
        return a and b

lsubstr('hweolrllod')
```

so I changed my code to this:

```
def lsubstr(x):

if len(x) <1:
        return x
else:
        return (lsubstr(x[2:])+str(x[0]),lsubstr(x[2:])+str(x[1]))
lsubstr('hweolrllod')
```

and what I am trying to make is a tuple which will store 2 pairs of characters and concatenate the next ones,

the error I get is 
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

what exactly is going wrong, I have checked in visualization, it has trouble in concatenating.

Comment: Yes, a function *can* return a string. Your issue, at least one of your issues, is that you're not returning from the recursive call at all (e.g. `return lsubstr(..)`). Secondarily, what is `a and b` supposed to return exactly?!

Comment: The `and` operator is normally used for boolean logic. I believe you want to use `+` to concatenate the strings.

Comment: Part of your problem may be that you aren't doing anything with the value returned from either of the calls to `lsubstr`. Perhaps you want to print it out or assign it to a variable or something?

Comment: if I am going to concatenate the strings, it wouldn't give me the desired results, infact it would make it a single string back again

Answer (score 2):

The `and` keyword is a boolean operator, which means it compares two values, and returns one of the values. I think you want to return a tuple instead, like this:

```
...
return (a, b)
```

And then you can access the values using the indexing operator like this:

```
a = lsubstr( ... )
a[0]
a[1]
```

Or:

```
word1, word2 = lsubstr( ... )
```

Comment: @deceze I've edited my question, if that makes anything better.

Comment: I might still take issue with the description of `and` being a "boolean" operator... but the rest makes a lot more sense now. ;o)

Comment: if I return anything like "return (a,b)" it gives me an error

Comment: "it gives me an error" is not useful to us. Exactly what error do you get?